# How can I manually create shortlinks for lots of news-articles?

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-10.x

I imported about 1,000 news-articles via database-import from a very old TYPO 3 installation. I can see the news in the overview, but will get an 404 when clicking for details. TYPO 3 is leading me to `http://domain.tld/category/detail/1061.html` but this page doesn't exist. After editing the article and creating a shortlink ("Sprechende URL Pfadabschnitt", jweiland-Mustertemplate), the details can be accessed in the frontend. But I don't want to do this for about 1,000 articles...

My question: Is there a way to create the shortlink automatically for all news or can I "teach" the extension to use the `1061.html` for the imported news?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance...

I'm using TYPO 3 10.4.11 and news 8.5.0.

Ralf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an upgrade wizard step if news is installed. You can use it in InstallTool Upgrade Wizard. The Wizard checks the field "path_segment" in news data. You can also fill in the field manually in database with the content of the news title field and replace characters that are not allowed in path segments. Spaces, "."  and similar. But I think the way with the upgrade wizard should work.

Comment: Karsten, the Upgrade Wizard worked fine! Thank you very much! :)